# ¿Cómo muestro las horas que no están tomadas en PHP con MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema ya que quiero desplegar un Select con todos los horarios disponibles para un especialista médico. Por ejemplo, el especialista 1907787-4 tiene ocupado el lunes de 8:00 a 10:00. Ocupo 3 tablas que son estas.

> Esta es mi primera tabla: **días**

[image: tabla]

> Esta es la segunda tabla: **turnos**

[image: turnos]

> Y finalmente las uno en la tercera tabla, que es
>   **horario_Especialistas**

[image: horario]

Si se dan cuenta ya tengo un registro de un médico que tiene ocupado el día 1 (Lunes) en horario 1 (de 08:00 a 10:00 hrs)

De qué manera podría crear la consulta en MySQL y aplicarla en un  en PHP para mostrar sólo los horarios disponibles del medico que se seleccione? Agradezco sus guías

Answer (score 1):

Interesante pregunta, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
select D.dia, GROUP_CONCAT(T.inicio,'-',T.fin) as turnos
from dias D, turnos T 
where concat(D.id_dia, '-', T.id_turno) not in(
    select concat(H.dia,'-',H.turno)
    from horario_especialistas H
    where H.rut_esp='15.827.714-K'
)
GROUP BY D.dia
order by D.id_dia, T.id_turno
```

Considerando que solo guardas los turnos ocupados en tu tabla `horario_especialistas` esta consulta te dará todos los turnos que no esta ocupando el especialista de la siguiente forma:

```
    dia   |        turnos
-------------------------------------
Lunes     |10:00-12:00,12:00-14:00
Martes    |8:00-10:00,10:00-12:00,12:00-14:00
Miercoles |8:00-10:00,10:00-12:00,12:00-14:00
Jueves    |8:00-10:00,10:00-12:00,12:00-14:00
Viernes   |8:00-10:00,10:00-12:00,12:00-14:00
Sabado    |8:00-10:00,10:00-12:00,12:00-14:00
Domingo   |8:00-10:00,10:00-12:00,12:00-14:00
```

y para obtener los turnos que un especialista esta ocupando (lo opuesto) para hacer pruebas puedes usar esta otra:

```
select D.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(T.inicio,'-',T.fin) as turnos
from dias D, turnos T, horario_especialistas H
where H.dia=D.id and H.turno=T.id and H.esp=1
GROUP BY D.nombre
order by D.id
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.